# How can I know the errors in cron script

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am trying to run the cron script. I get an email everytime cron runs but I realise that the script does not run via cron job. However, when I try to run that script using browser direct link, it works fine.

I just wondering that how can I know what is happening in background when cron runs?

I tried to write it to log file but this either does not work !

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );
```

Any help?

Comment: have you tried manually running the cron jon in the terminal?

Comment: So the cron job probably isn't working. You need to add your cron job code here for us to help.

Comment: cron job script is working because when it try it using web browser then it works like charm ..

Comment: I have not tried manually running the cron job. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some path issue. Add your email id where you added cron job in cpanel. Then they will email you the bug when cron job runs.